# Removing wording in front and back of a string via regex or use replace instead?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I want to remove wording from the front and end of a string (taken from page title of Google Slide in presenter view)

> Presenter view - Custom title may contain numbers or special characters - Google Slides

Since the middle part may contain anything unexpected, would using replace() be better than regex?

I want to remove: "Presenter view - " and " - Google Slides", which I expect always to be the same. The below works for me:

```
const slidetitle = document.title.replace("Presenter view - ", "").replace("- Google Slides", "");
```

With regex I tried below but not working:

```
const slidetitle = document.title.match(/(?<=Presenter view - ).*(?<= - Google Slides)$/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
/^[^-]+- | -[^-]+$/gm
```

- `^[^-]+-`  - capture everything not a dash from the beginning of the line leading up to dash+space
- `|` - or
- `-[^-]+$` - find the last space+dash and capture everything not a dash till the end of the line
- `gm` - global+multiline modifiers

```js
console.log(`Presenter view - Custom title may contain numbers or special characters - Google Slides`.replace(/^[^-]+- | -[^-]+$/gm, ''));
```

---

Using the solution above affords you the chance that "Presenter view - " and " - Google Slides" are not guaranteed. If they are guaranteed then:

```
/^Presenter view - | - Google Slides$/gm
```

Comment: Thanks, the last one worked, given that it's guaranteed. Btw. just wondering if regex would be better than replace? Any advantage in performance or anything else?

Comment: @Markus You seem to have your terminology a bit mixed up. Are you asking whether replacement is better than extraction? If so then benchmark the difference; I sincerely doubt you're doing anything which would generate a noticeable difference. As you can see I am making use of regex in the replacement because regex supports line anchors. Try your original solutions on something like `Presenter view - Custom title explaining why the "Presenter view - " prefix is bad - Google Slides`. I used regex instead of string replacement because it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: yeah sorry just realised that, i meant comparing the exact string search vs regex pattern. Cool I'll try that.Also I celebrated to early, using the last approach results in  `Presenter view - , - Google Slides` but the main one works.

Comment: I have no idea where that comma came from, you likely have a typo in your code. Anyways, crafting a regex for replacement is different than crafting one for extraction. Pick a methodology and stick to it. My answer clearly uses `.replace()` so if you're not using `.replace()` then that is your culprit.

Comment: indeed, fixed now, thanks that worked, and for explaining